# Constructing an AND statement in SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a SQLite database table with three columns: order_id, item, quantity. Each row has an order_id, an item, and a quantity.

I am trying to write a query that finds orders that contain two different items (item1 and item2), so that my output looks something like this:

```
order_id | item   | quantity
---------------------------
1234     | item1  |  7
---------------------------
1234     | item2  |  2
---------------------------
5678     | item1  |  5
---------------------------
5678     | item2  |  3
```

This is the code I've cobbled together so far:

`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE term=? AND term=?", [("item1"), ("item2")])`

If I use an `OR` statement, I get what I would expect. I understand logically why this is not working with `AND`, but I can't figure out the SQL statement that will make it work.

Comment: This is neither a Python nor an SQLite question, but a pure SQL one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inner join two `Order` tables on `order_id`:

```
sql = '''SELECT o1.*, o2.*
FROM Orders as o1
INNER JOIN Orders as o2
ON o1.order_id = o2.order_id
WHERE o1.item = ?
    AND o2.item = ?'''

args = ("item1", "item2")
cur.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: So as I interpret this, basically I create a table, order_table_1, from searching on item1, then create order_table_2 from searching on item2, then do an INNER JOIN on the two tables. Sorry this is so elementary; it is my first stab at SQL.

Comment: That is basically correct except for the order of operations. The `Orders` table already exists. The `INNER JOIN` is performed first, it joins rows from `o1` (the first copy of `Orders`) with rows from `o2` whenever `o1.order_id = o2.order_id`. Think of the rows as being concatentated horizontally. You end up with a big table. This big table is then reduced by the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Here is a [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Awesome. That explains things a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all orders that have an item1 and an item2 then you want a self join and that output try

```
Select * From (    
select * from sometable I1
    inner join someTable i2 on I1.Order_Id = I2.Order_ID
    Where I1.item = 'item1' and I2.Item = 'item2'
    union  
    select * from sometable I2
    inner join someTable i1 on I2.Order_Id = I1.Order_ID
    Where I2.item = 'item2' and I1.Item = 'item1'
) both 
order by Order_id,item, quantity desc
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, using a count subquery and inner join.

```
# setup
import sqlite3
cnxn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Orders (order_id integer, item text, quantity integer)")
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, item, quantity) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
""", [(1234, 'item1', 7), (1234, 'item2', 4), (4567, 'item1', 3)])

# answer
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT Orders.order_id, Orders.item, Orders.quantity 
    FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) AS cnt FROM Orders GROUP BY order_id) Orders_count
    ON Orders.order_id = Orders_count.order_id
    WHERE Orders_count.cnt > 1
""")

results = cursor.fetchall()
# [(1234, u'item1', 7), (1234, u'item2', 4)]
cnxn.close()
```